# Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am getting error of Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259
while running below query, I tried with giving database name also but it is not working getting same error again and again. Can someone help me out in this regards.

```
declare @subject_line varchar (200)
  declare @sql_query varchar (8000)
  set @subject_line=(select 'Find Highest - ' + convert 
  (varchar(25),getdate(),120))
  set @sql_query=(select 'select a.productname, a.groupid, c.productstatus, 
  releasedate from #tmpa a
  join #tmpb b on a.productname = b.productname and a.prodgroupseqnr = b.maxpg
  left join [Repository_PROD].[dbo].[Product_Info] c on a.productname = 
  c.product_EDP
  order by 1')

  EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
  @recipients=N'abc@gmail.com',
  @subject= @subject_line,
  @body= 'Hi ,

  Please find attached output of given query .


  Regards,
  SQLDBA_TEAM
  ',
  @execute_query_database = 'Repository_PROD',
  @query_result_header = 1,
  @query= @sql_query,
  @profile_name ='SQLDBA',
  @query_result_width=6000,
  @query_result_separator ='    ',
  @query_no_truncate = 1,
  @query_result_no_padding = 1,
  @query_attachment_filename ='Find Highest.xls',
  @attach_query_result_as_file = 1 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a temporary table when using database mail.  You'll also need to include the database name in all tables that are being accessed, for example,
FROM ' + DB_NAME() + '.dbo.TableName makes it portable across databases.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. Then I found the user who is calling the job is not added in SQL server logins folder of Security. I added that user in Security->Logins. It is working fine.